# Jsoup and "image"

Tags: xml, jsoup

I tried to parse XML file using Java Jsoup.

XML:

```
<images>
  <image>http://site.ru/xml_examples/photos/photo1.jpg</image>
  <image>http://site.ru/xml_examples/photos/photo2.jpg</image>
  <image>http://site.ru/xml_examples/photos/photo3.jpg</image>
</images>
```

Code:

```
org.jsoup.Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(feedUrl)
                .header("User-Agent", RPL.USER_AGENT)
                .method(org.jsoup.Connection.Method.GET)
                .timeout(60000)
                .execute();
doc = res.parse();
SysLog2.debug("doc = " + doc);
```

Output:

```
<images>
  <img />http://site.ru/xml_examples/photos/photo1.jpg
  <img />http://site.ru/xml_examples/photos/photo2.jpg
  <img />http://site.ru/xml_examples/photos/photo3.jpg
</images>
```

My question: What happens with my "**image**" tag? How I can disable such transformation?

Comment: You should provide the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION (use 'xmlParser'):**

```
org.jsoup.Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(feedUrl)
                .header("User-Agent", RPL.USER_AGENT)
                .method(org.jsoup.Connection.Method.GET)
                .timeout(60000)
                .execute();
doc = Jsoup.parse(res.toString(), "", Parser.xmlParser());
```